# zoom sdk integration in swift iOS. facing issue on up-gradation meeting sdkv5.14.11.8690

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-push-notifications, zoom-sdk

Facing issue on up-gradation of Meeting SDK to v5.14.11.8690 “Value of type ‘MobileRTCAuthService’ has no member ‘clientKey’ and Value of type ‘MobileRTCAuthService’ has no member ‘clientSecret’”

Please give me an updated code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they have removed the `clientSecret` and `clientKey` properties.
I have replaced those two with JWT as described here https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/auth/ and succeeded to connect.